# springer journal template

Tags: affiliation, springernature

Please, Why I get on the dot like the attached image between the authors name? I got on a circle not dot. The same thing with keywords.

This is my code:

\author{ first  $^{1,3}$    \and  second $^{2}$ \and third $^{2}$  \and firsrtA $^{3}$
}

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{algorithm}
%%%\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol,utfsym,arev}
\usepackage{stix,bbding,pifont,utfsym,fontawesome}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%%%\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}
\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
%%% \usepackage{subcaption}
%%%\usepackage{subfig}
%%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
%%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 


\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}

% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
 \journalname{The Journal of Supercomputing}

%
\begin{document}

\title{HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH }
%\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

%\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head

\author{ first  $^{1,3}$    \and  second$^{2}$ \and third $^{2}$  \and third_s$^{3}$ 
     %   Second Author %etc.
}    
    \date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
    % The correct dates will be entered by the editor
    
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    \keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
    % \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
    % \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
    \end{abstract}
    \end{document}
    % end of file template.tex
```

Comment: Please tell us exactly which of Springer's many LaTeX template files you use.

Comment: Sorry, What the files you meant?

Comment: show a small one page complete document that makes the output shown, and a link to the template you used

Comment: please don't use minted in examples (you can not expect peopel to use shell-escape) but apart from that the example gibes the error `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.85     \maketitle
`

Comment: Don't load packages you don't know about. It's nonsense to do `\usepackage{stix}` along with `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`, nor to load `tabu` (which is unmaintained and very buggy). Start with a simple preamble and add what you ***really*** need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the package

`\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`

and the centred dots are restored

[image]

In general, journal document classes are set up to use the fonts chosen by the journal and are not intended to be customised.

Comment: Well, `svjour3` doesn't use Times-like fonts by default…

Comment: @egreg well yes the comment in my question was a hint that none of the font packages should be loaded if you are submitting to a journal.